# How can I convert a byte in textureImage to a float?

Tags: c, opengl

I have to convert a `TextureImage[][][]` which it's type in `GLubyte` (each element represents different color of pixel in the texture image) to a `GLfloat` variable that represents a color. I have to do it without any of *openGL* commands.
Here is my code:

```
GLubyte TextureImage[TEXTURE_SIZE][TEXTURE_SIZE][3];
GLfloat pixColor1 , pixColor2 , pixColor3;
                            pixColor1 = (GLfloat)(GLint)TextureImage[t][s][0];
                            pixColor2 = (GLfloat)(GLint)TextureImage[t][s][1];
                            pixColor3 = (GLfloat)(GLint)TextureImage[t][s][2];
                            pixColor1 /= 255.0;
                            pixColor2 /= 255.0;
                            pixColor3 /= 255.0;
```

Comment: Ok.  Did you intend to ask a question?  You seem to already have an answer to the one posed in the title.

Comment: It appears you are double typecasting here: `pixColor1 = (GLfloat)(GLint)TextureImage[t][s][0];`, is that your intent?  What you asked seems to suggest that you want to typecast to `GLfloat` which would make the statement `pixColor1 = (GLfloat)TextureImage[t][s][0];`

Comment: I have to get the value of the pixel in the texture image (rgb color)..the type of the texture image is GLubyte..I want to read this byte and turn it to GLfloat..because I want to ''paint'' the pixel of the screen..and my function that paints the pixel can get only float numbers (the rgb colors).

Comment: You're code appears *already* to get the components of the three color channels of a pixel as values of type `GLfloat`, in the range 0.0 - 1.0, inclusive.  So again, what's the actual question?

Comment: it still doesn't work..I think that the mistake is from there, but im not sure..do you think that this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

*"...convert a byte in textureImage to a float?"*

First an aside:

According to the [OpenGL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf):

> ...`GL`  types  are  not `C` types.   Thus,  for  example,  `GLtype int` is referred to as `GLint` outside this document, and is not
> necessarily equivalent to the `C` type `int`. An implementation must
> use exactly the number of bits indicated in the table to represent a
> GL type.

So although we do not know exactly what `C` type `GLint` is equivalent to, we do know that it is 32 bits wide (4 bytes), not 8 bits (1 byte) as would be true for `byte` (native type `unsigned char`)

Making the question *How can I convert a byte in textureImage to a float?* seem suspicious as to what you are really doing, because the type of `GLint` is not `==` to a `byte`.  This not withstanding

Because OpenGL is a library rooted in C, the type conversion is done like any other, using a type cast with caution:

In this case the width specified in the standard for both `GLint` and `GLfloat` are both 32 bits wide but width alone does not eliminate the risks, as @Margaret Bloom mentions in comments:

> Beware that integers cannot be converted to float safely. One valid
> implementation of a float (actually the one used on almost all
> architectures) is through the IEEE754 binary32 format. This only has
> 23 bits of mantissa. A number like 0xFFFFFFFF cannot be converted
> exactly to float.

With that said, The typecast would be syntactically identical to any other typecast in `C`

the statement :

```
pixColor1 = (GLfloat)(GLint)TextureImage[t][s][0]; 
            //       ^^^^^^^ this part is not necessary but does not change the assigned value

pixColor1 = (GLfloat)TextureImage[t][s][0];//modified to eliminate (GLint)
```

Effectively casts the value contained in `TextureImage[t][s][0]` to a `GLfloat`.  The same as the pure `C` example below does:

```
float someFloatVal = (float)someIntegerArray[a][b][c];
```

Comment: Beware that integers cannot be converted to float safely. One valid implementation of a float (actually the one used on almost all architectures) is through the IEEE754 binary32 format. This only has 23 bits of mantissa. A number like 0xFFFFFFFF cannot be converted exactly to float. Yet both are 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I've figured out the problem. I probably had to move "GLubyte" variable to an "unsigned char" variable and only after then turn it to integer and float.

```
GLubyte TextureImage[TEXTURE_SIZE][TEXTURE_SIZE][3];
GLfloat pixColor1 , pixColor2 , pixColor3;
unsigned int temp1, temp2, temp3;
unsigned char r, g, b;

r = TextureImage[s][t][0];
g = TextureImage[s][t][1];
b = TextureImage[s][t][2];
temp1 = r + '0';
temp2 = g + '0';
temp3 = b + '0';
pixColor1 = temp1/255.0;
pixColor2 = temp2/255.0;
pixColor3 = temp3/255.0;
```

Comment: `temp1 = r + '0';
temp2 = g + '0';
temp3 = b + '0';` This looks really wrong. Please, note that `unsigned char` (in opposition to what the type may impose by its name) is just an integral type with 1 byte. Although characters are usually stored as `char`s or `unsigned char`s, this doesn't mean that every value of `unsigned char` represents a character. In your case (of `GLubyte TextureImage[TEXTURE_SIZE][TEXTURE_SIZE][3];`), it surely does not.

Comment: I would recommend instead: `pixColor1 = TextureImage[s][t][0] / 255.0; pixColor2 = TextureImage[s][t][1] / 255.0; pixColor3 = TextureImage[s][t][2] / 255.0;`. The division `x / 255.0` will force the conversion of the `GLubyte x` to `double` as well (due to type promotion). I made a small [MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ceb5c2eac551ec5) to show how smooth this works for all possible values of `GLubyte` (aka. `unsigned char` in C and C++).

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that you tagged [tag:c]. So, the [MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db853d1829095548) - ported to C. ;-)